# Creating MyISAM Table in Azure database for MySQL is enable?

Tags: mysql, innodb, azure-database-mysql

When I create table that engine is MyISAM in Azure database for Mysql, Got Error "ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 1 from storage engine"

How do I fix it?
or can I use MyISAM table in Azure database for MySQL?

[image: cli screen captuer]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Correct - MYISAM is not supported in Azure Database for MySQL, primarily due to the lack of transaction support which can potentially lead to data loss.  This is one of the reasons MySQL switched over to InnoDB as the default.

Jason
Azure DB for MySQL team

Comment: Thank you!! I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know MYISAM is not supported in Azure database for MySQL. I'd suggest you switch to InnoDB instead.

In addition, I've also found a [similar feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597982-azure-database-for-mysql/suggestions/19271050-add-myisam-engine-support) in Azure feedback site.I'd suggest you keep track of that to see if anything changes.

Regards,
Lin

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue but getting this error on my local mysql database. I would suggest that the first thing you do is check the storage engine.

In my case it turned out that the storage engine was `ARCHIVE` and changing this to `InnoDB` solved the issue.